# Add columns from different dataframes to target dataframe in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a few dataframes like this:

```
 rdd_1 = sc.parallelize([(0,10,"A",2), (1,20,"B",1), (2,30,"A",2)])
 rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([(0,10,223,"201601"), (0,10,83,"2016032"),(1,20,3213,"201602"),(1,20,3003,"201601"), (1,20,9872,"201603"), (2,40, 2321,"201601"), (2,30, 10,"201602"),(2,61, 2321,"201601")])
 df_tg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_1, ["id", "type", "route_a", "route_b"])
 df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_2, ["id", "type", "cost", "date"])

 df_tg.show()


+---+----+-------+-------+
| id|type|route_a|route_b|
+---+----+-------+-------+
|  0|10  |      A|      2|
|  1|20  |      B|      1|
|  2|30  |      A|      2|
+---+----+-------+-------+

df_data.show()   

+---+----+----+------+
| id|type|cost|  date|
+---+----+----+------+
|  0|10  | 223|201603|
|  0|10  | 83 |201602|
|  1|20  |3003|201601|
|  1|20  |3213|201602|
|  1|20  |9872|201603|
|  2|30  |  10|201602|
|  2|30  |  62|201601|
|  2|40  |2321|201601|
+---+----+----+------+
```

So I need to add the columns like this:

```
+---+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| id|type|route_a|route_b|cost_201603|cost_201602|cost_201601|
+---+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  0|10  |      A|      2|       223 |   83      |       None|
|  1|20  |      B|      1|      9872 |     3213  |       3003|
|  2|30  |      A|      2|      None |   10      |         62|
+---+----+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

For this I would have to do a few joins:

```
df_tg = df_tg.join(df_data[df_data.date == "201603"], ["id", "type"])
```

and with that I would have to rename the columns too, to not overwrite them:

```
df_tg = df_tg.join(df_data[df_data.date == "201603"], ["id", "type"]).withColumnRenamed("cost","cost_201603")
```

I can write a function to do this, but I would have to loop through both the dates available and the columns, generating ton of joins with full table scans:

```
def feature_add(df_target, df_feat, feat_cols, period):
    for ref_month in period:
        df_target = df_target.join(df_feat, ["id", "type"]).select(
                *[df_target[column] for column in df_target.columns] + [df_feat[feat_col]]
                ).withColumnRenamed(feat_col, feat_col + '_' + ref_month)
    return df_target

df_tg = feature_add(df_tg, df_data, ["cost"], ["201602", "201603", "201601"])
```

This works, but it's terrible. How can I add these columns, including when I'm calling the same function for other dataframes? Notice that the columns are not perfectly aligned and I need to do a inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use pivot functions as following :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

rdd_1 = sc.parallelize([(0,10,"A",2), (1,20,"B",1), (2,30,"A",2)])
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([(0,10,223,"201601"), (0,10,83,"2016032"),(1,20,3213,"201602"),(1,20,3003,"201601"), (1,20,9872,"201603"), (2,40, 2321,"201601"), (2,30, 10,"201602"),(2,61, 2321,"201601")])
df_tg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_1, ["id", "type", "route_a", "route_b"])
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_2, ["id", "type", "cost", "date"])

pivot_df_data = df_data.groupBy("id","type").pivot("date").agg({"cost" : "sum"})

pivot_df_data.join(df_tg, ['id','type'], 'inner').select('id','type','route_a','route_b','201601','201602','201603','2016032').show()

# +---+----+-------+-------+------+------+------+-------+
# | id|type|route_a|route_b|201601|201602|201603|2016032|
# +---+----+-------+-------+------+------+------+-------+
# |  0|  10|      A|      2|   223|  null|  null|     83|
# |  1|  20|      B|      1|  3003|  3213|  9872|   null|
# |  2|  30|      A|      2|  null|    10|  null|   null|
# +---+----+-------+-------+------+------+------+-------+
```